# AMP - which pages should be made into AMP

Tags: html, ajax, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I'm currently having an audit of a site and trying to determine which pages can benefit from being made into AMP. The help page is a given. It's a static, text only page. I also have a film details page which based on an id will display the related content. This page has a signed in/out state and also has an edit button which will allow a signed in user to edit the contents. Finally I have an ajax search page.

My questions are:

- For the film details page, would this be a good candidate for an AMP?
- How would I deal with the signed out/in state?
- How would I deal with the edit button on the film details page?
- Would it be worth creating an AMP version of the ajax search page?

Comment: These are good questions but should probably be asked separately.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking only static pages which are going to be getting traffic from Google search or social media or good candidates for AMP pages.  So your film details page is an excellent candidate.  The edit button on the page will take the reader to the regular version.  Since Google will try to cache the AMP pages, you generally would not be able to have any signed-in state.  If a user signs in, they go to the regular page.  I would also argue against creating an AMP version of the search page, as again, it's dynamic content.